# Maximum Week and last 8 weeks in Date Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a Table where time dimension column is in Weeks grain. Below is the sample data present

```
Date_Column
2022-07-30
2022-07-23
2022-07-16
2022-07-09
2022-07-02
2022-06-25
2022-06-18
2022-06-11
2022-06-04
```

I need to find only Max(Date-Column) and 4 more weeks(Date_Column) value using query. I am trying with DATEADD Function but its not giving desired result

my desired result will be

```
Date_Column
2022-07-30
2022-07-23
2022-07-16
2022-07-09
2022-07-02
```

I am trying with this SQL query

```
DATEADD(DAY,-7*5,DATE_COLUMN)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want the past 4 weeks (28 days) inclusive from the latest date in the table

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE DATEADD(day, 28, DATE_COLUMN) >= (SELECT MAX(DATE_COLUMN) FROM yourTable);
```

Comment: Since the table is already divided into weeks, a `TOP 5` or `row_number()` solution might also work.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen thanks your solution worked

Answer (score 1):

you can use Row_number() in the descending order and select top 5 ranks.

```sql
DECLARE @table table(date_column date)

insert into @table values
('2022-07-30')
,('2022-07-23')
,('2022-07-16')
,('2022-07-09')
,('2022-07-02')
,('2022-06-25')
,('2022-06-18')
,('2022-06-11')
,('2022-06-04');

SELECT t.date_column 
from
(SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY DATE_COLUMN DESC) AS Rnk_desc FROM @TABLE ) as t
WHERE t.Rnk_desc < = 5

-- Or

SELECT TOP 5 date_column 
FROM @TABLE 
order by date_column desc
```

| date_column |
| --- |
| 2022-07-30 |
| 2022-07-23 |
| 2022-07-16 |
| 2022-07-09 |
| 2022-07-02 |

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, as OP has mentioned that data already in weeks grain, I took this approach.

Comment: Yes Always Date_Column is one week apart but I need to filter Date_Column as existing sql will be difficult to change instead to add filter in the Date_Column

Comment: in your case, you dont need filter, as you want maximum date_column and the previous 4 weeks.

Comment: `TOP 5` seems to be simpler.

Comment: @Charlieface, agree with you. updated my answer